# Accessing relationships within the after_insert and before_insert event hooks when using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two very related questions about manipulating relationships in SQLAlchemy event hooks. Note I'm using `flask-sqlalchemy` and essentially the same model as below.

1) **edit** I'm trying to add an event listener for the Record object so that I do something to the `people` in a Record instance after it has been created by the Record default initializer. The only problem is `target` in the `do_action` body doesn't have the `people` list appended, whereas the `people` list is present after the instance is created. What's the reason for this and is there a workaround for `do_action`?

My model:

```py
record_structure = db.Table(
    'record_structure',
    db.Column('person_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id')),
    db.Column('record_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('record.id')))

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)

class Record(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'record'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)
    people = db.relationship('Person', secondary=record_structure)

    def __init__(self, name, people):
        self.name = name
        self.people = list()
        self.people.extend(people)

@db.event.listens_for(Record, 'after_insert')
def do_action(mapper, connection, target):
    print(target.name) # output 'my record'
    print(len(target.people)) # output: 0 ??
    # do something with target.people
```

My load_db.py

```
p1 = Person(name='tom')
p2 = Person(name='fred')
db.session.add(p1)
db.session.add(p2)
db.session.commit()
r = Record('my record', [p1, p2])
print(len(r.people)) # output: 2
db.session.add(r)
db.session.commit()
```

2) If there is a workaround for the 'after_insert' event hook. Is there a workaround if I replace the hook with a 'before_insert' event hook?

Comment: `r = Record('my record', [p1, p2])` and `def __init__(self, name, labels):`. Your list of people is being passed to the labels argument .

Comment: Oh my bad, that was a typo. Updated question

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. When I run your code, `len(target.people) == 2`.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the code I provided in 1) is completely fine so `len(target.people) == 2` and 2) holds as well. My original code was slightly different and that's what caused the `len(target.people) == 0`. The `bookkeeper.records.append(self)` seems to have caused a premature insert and caused `self.people` to initialize as empty list. Thanks @SuperShoot for trying to reproduce it.

```py
class Record(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'record'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)
    people = db.relationship('Person', secondary=record_structure)

    def __init__(self, name, bookkeeper, people):
        self.name = name
        bookkeeper.records.append(self)
        self.people = list()
        self.people.extend(people)
```

I guess a good practice is to put lines that pass `self` like `bookkeeper.records.append(self)` at the end of `__init__` so relevant data is passed to event hooks.